# Why do we need "assign" in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am going through an example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). I see there the following sequence of operations:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s = tf.Session()
s.run(init_op)
s.run(inc_v1)
```

As a result we get:

```py
array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

I do not understand the logic behind "assign" operation. In particular I have replaced it by something that looks much simpler to me:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1 = v1 + 1
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s = tf.Session()
s.run(init_op)
s.run(inc_v1)
```

And I got exactly the same output. So, why do we need assign?

Answer (score 2):

It takes your original tensor and a new tensor, updates original value of your tensor with a new value and returns the reference of your original tensor. Take a look at the graphs generated on Tensorboard:

The operation `assign` returns a reference to the original Tensor:

[image: Assign]

Without `assign`, just creates another tensor to add a constant value:

[image: No Assign]

If you print the evaluation of the tensor `v1` (after running `inc_v1`) it outputs `[1. 1. 1.]` as the result of the operation its been reassigned to the original tensor. In the second case, it will remain as `[0. 0. 0.]`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some little explanation at the end ;)

Answer (score 2):

That example is indeed not very illustrative. The important part is that `assign` saves the given value to the variable within the session, so you can use it later in the next call to `run`. See here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print(sess.run(v1))
    # [1. 1. 1.]
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print(sess.run(v1))
    # [2. 2. 2.]
```

Note `v1` saves the assigned value, so in further calls to `run` it can be used. Compare now to:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1 = v1+1
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print(sess.run(v1))
    # [0. 0. 0.]
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print(sess.run(v1))
    # [0. 0. 0.]
```

Here the increment happens within one call to `run`, but its result is never saved anywhere, and `v1` keeps having the value `[0. 0. 0.]`.

Variables are important because most things in TensorFlow are done on several steps, e.g. each batch in a neural network. Each step is a call to `run`, and it is important that the changes to a model in a step (e.g. the updates to the weights in a neural network) are saved for the next step - otherwise you would be running in place, never leaving the starting point!

Answer (score 0):

You need assign when you want to assign a value that does not come from the graph

Comment: What do you mean by "come from graph"? To set a value of "inc_v1" we use "v1". Can we say that the value comes from a graph in that case?

Comment: @Roman yes. Examples of things not coming from the graph would be things coming from a _different_ graph, a file, user input, etc.